Disable Spring's method security for unit tests with Spring Boot 3
I am using @PreAuthorize on methods in service interfaces. Theses services are used by @RestController classes
With Spring Boot 2.x I enabled method security in a AutoConfiguration with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
In some @SpringBootTests we concentrate on testing the functional logic and don't care about method security. Theses tests do no call a rest service or controller class. They directly call method from above mentioned service classes which are annotated with @PreAuthorize. In these tests we disabled the method security by
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class MyTestApplication extends MySringBootApplication {

    @Bean
    public GeFaJwtInterceptorTestAspect jwtInterceptorTestAspect() {
        return new GeFaJwtInterceptorTestAspect();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    SecurityMetadataSource disableMethodSecurityForUnitTest() {
        return new DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(Maps.newLinkedHashMap());
    }
}

That works fine.
After migration to Spring Boot 3 I am using @EnableMethodSecurity now.
How can I disable Spring's security method in unit tests?
I read the article https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#enable-annotation but did not find a solution there.
I tried out

using @EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false) at MyTestApplication
adding a bean in my test configuration
  @Bean
  @Primary
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> disableMethodSecurityForUnitTest1() {
      return (authentication, object) -> new AuthorizationDecision(true);
  }



But that did not work. Each try end up with one of the following exceptions
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

Currently my only fix is to add @WithMockUser on each test method which is not what I want as I want to test the functional logic only. (Method security is tested, too, but on another layer in our application.)

Is disabling the whole security configuration for test an option for you? Or do you want to disable method security only?

If disabling method security only can be done, this would be our first choice. But as you ask maybe it is not possible, then disabling the whole security would also fit.

Thank you very much @Mar-Z. That brings me to to the idea of disabling by separating the AutoConfiguration. That trigger helped a lot!

Thank's to Mar-Z answer I came to the clue to disable it by excluding the AutoConfiguration which activates the MethodSecurity.
Currently I only had one AutoConfigration in my maven module. That holds a couple of different Beans/ aspects. So at first I had to separate that AutoConfiguration into two parts. A second AutoConfiguration which only holds the configuration for activating the method security
As exclude does only works for AutoConfiguration it must be an AutoConfiguration - Configuration only does not work

@AutoConfiguration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MyServiceSecurityAutoConfiguration {
    // you could add any Beans here relevant for Authorization / method security etc.
}

Of course the class has to be added to src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports
In my SpringBootTest I excluded this AutoConfiguration like this
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
          classes = {MyIntegrationTestApplication.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.ANY)
@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "console", "test"})
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    // any tests here

}

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MyServiceSecurityAutoConfiguration .class})
class MyIntegrationTestApplication extends MySpringBootApplication {

    // Maybe you need to define some mandatory beans here if they are not loaded by AutoConfiguration
}

If you do not need to extend the SpringBootApplication (here MySpringBootApplication) by any additional bean you can also do this to exclude the MethodeSecurity-Configuration in your test:
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MySpringBootApplication .class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MyServiceSecurityAutoConfiguration .class})
class MyIntegrationTest {

    // any tests here

}

May be that helps other members, too.

This is what I'm using to switch the security off for local run or testing.

Disable auto-configuration per default

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {
// ...
}


Use profile (for example test) to deactivate the security configuration class

@Profile("!test")
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
// ...
}

Similar to this you can provide a separate configuration class and profile to switch off the method security only.
@Profile("!test2")
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
}

